# How can I rerender an array of components in react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, frontend

I'm traing to make an experiment in react and websockets. The web app sends an input from the user to a server and the server responds. For each response from the server the web creates a component to show the response. I don't know how to rerender the array after each response.

```
import React, { useState, Component } from 'react'
import './HomePage2.css'

import Text from '../../commons/Text/Text'
import Input from '../../commons/Input/Input'
import TextInput from '../../commons/TextInput/TextInput'

const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:5656')

var path = 'path$ '
var items = []

const hc = () =>{
    this.forceUpdate()
}

ws.addEventListener("message", data => {
    console.log(data.data)
    items.push(<TextInput path={path} text={data.data} />)
    //items.push(data.data)
    if(data.data !== ''){
        items.push(<Text text={data.data} />)
    }
})

class HomePage2 extends Component {

    render(){

        function setCommand(comm){
            ws.send(comm)
        }
    
        return(
            <div className='homepage2' >
                {items}
                <Input path={path} callback={setCommand} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default HomePage2
```

Answer (score 0):

save received data in an array and use the map method to render an element for each value in the array, e.g:

```
return (
  <>
    {items.map((item, key) => (
      <TextInput path={path} text={item.data} key={key} />
    ))}
  </>
);
```